# Adding Icon/Icon Links

Tags: css

I was wondering how to add an Icon link to a webpage. I.e a picture of the twitter logo and once clicked it goes to your twitter page.

I'm specifically wondering how the logo is made like that, is it a custom image or what?

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry to specify I mean I am wondering if there is a database of icons that you can use for links or if they are created by the person that designed the web, not how to link a picture.

Comment: Yes; it is possible to put an image in a webpage.  What is your question?

Comment: Put the `<img>` inside an `<a>`?

Comment: http://uwvsa.clubs.feds.ca/ 
In the follow section the logos that are the links. How are those made?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons.  Yes, it's very simple to use them as a link.  Simply embed the external CSS file into your HTML, and add the respective classes to your items.  Try something like this for your twitter image:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- This embeds the Font Awesome icons -->

<a href="https://twitter.com/myTwitterURL"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there documentation for maxcdn?